# С - ограничить ввод числовыми значениями

Tags: c

Как в си ограничить ввод числовыми значениями, чтобы при вводе буквенных значений выдавало ошибку?

Comment: Добавте в вопрос фрагмент вашего кода.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите проверять, введена ли цифра из дипазона `0-9`, используйте функцию `isdigit(character)` и в случае возврата ею значения `0` выводите ошибку. Пример:

```
#include <ctype.h> // заголовочный файл для isdigit
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;

    for (;;)
    {
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == ' ') break;
        if(isdigit(ch)) printf("%c is a digit\n", ch);
        else printf("error");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: При локали utf8 на little endian архитектуре будет весело смотреться ввод кириллицы в качестве теста.